# await/async Microsoft Practices Enterprise Library Data

Tags: c#, ado.net, async-await, enterprise-library, asp.net-4.5

I have an older application that I wrote where I used `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data` to get data from the DB.  I have recently upgraded to .NET 4.5 and wanted to advantage of **await/async**.

I do not see any methods ending in "Async" as per the naming standard, even in the most recent version of the package.  Is it possible to use await/async with this ADO .NET library without manually making it asynchronous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually was able to find the Async methods.  I was just looking in the wrong spots.  Here's two common ways of accessing the DB asynchronously:

```
var db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(GlobalConstants.DBConnection);
using (var cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("SprocName", parameterA))
{
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

and when you want to get data:

```
var db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(GlobalConstants.DBConnection);
using (var cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("SprocName", parameterA, parameterB, parameterC))
{
    using (var dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
    {
        while (await dr.ReadAsync())
        {
            return dr.GetInt32(0);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `GetFieldValueAsync<T>` instead of `GetInt32` if you are using `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` with large amounts of data.  But, for most cases, you probably do not need to do this.

Comment: What about opening the connection ?

Comment: I actually don't see these methods now..I got the latest enterprise library data through Nuget and still not able to find these methods..Can you let me know the version of ent lib?

Comment: ExecuteReaderAsync is not from enterprise library - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is why I hate the use of "var" of online samples.  You cannot see what they are.  While this is a good answer for SqlClient.........the original question was about "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data"   Please post "using" statements in your sample so this is clearer to the reader.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using an older version of the EL that offers Begin* / End* methods, but not async versions.  Some simple extension methods simplify life:

```
public static async Task<IDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(this SqlDatabase database, DbCommand command)
{
    return await Task<IDataReader>.Factory.FromAsync(database.BeginExecuteReader, database.EndExecuteReader, command, null);
}

public static async Task<object> ExecuteScalarAsync(this SqlDatabase database, DbCommand command)
{
    return await Task<object>.Factory.FromAsync(database.BeginExecuteScalar, database.EndExecuteScalar, command, null);
}

public static async Task<XmlReader> ExecuteXmlReaderAsync(this SqlDatabase database, DbCommand command)
{
    return await Task<XmlReader>.Factory.FromAsync(database.BeginExecuteXmlReader, database.EndExecuteXmlReader, command, null);
}

public static async Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(this SqlDatabase database, DbCommand command)
{
    return await Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(database.BeginExecuteNonQuery, database.EndExecuteNonQuery, command, null);
}
```

Comment: #beautiful   I updated all my layers (async/await) and found some Enterprise.Library.Data calls..and found this nugget.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there anyway to wire it to honor a CancellationToken?  #askingForAFriend  (especially ExecuteReaderAsync)

Comment: @granadaCoder, I don't think there's an elegant methods to do so; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980427/task-factory-fromasync-with-cancellationtokensource

Comment: That answer (accepted one from Stefan Z Camilleri) makes sense.  Thanks for followup.

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably find that it has methods like `BeginXXX` and `EndXXXX`, you can use those in conjunction with `Task.Factory.FromAsync`. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here is an example of using it to read a file using `Task.Factory.FromAsync` in conjunction with `filestream.BeginRead` and `filestream.EndRead`

```
private async Task<string> ReadFileAsync()
{
  var fileStream = File.OpenRead("..\\..\\..\\test.txt"); 
  var buffer = new byte[1024];

  await Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(fileStream.BeginRead, fileStream.EndRead, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null);

  return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

This package was written initially in .NET 4.0. 
If you look at their source, they don't use async/await anywhere. 
http://topaz.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#source/Source/TransientFaultHandling/AsyncExecution.cs