# How can I kill this task in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm checking a URL and start a new task to prevent UI freezing.

Like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;              
request.Method = "HEAD";
var response = (HttpWebResponse)await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse,request.EndGetResponse,null);
```

The point is.. I'm implemented a max time (for example 10 seconds).
If the app  reach 10 seconds without response, the task must be aborted.

Comment: Hint: Start a new thread so that UI do not hang. Then kill thread based on your condition.

Comment: Check out the proposed solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494502/implementing-extension-method-webrequest-getresponseasync-with-support-for-cance)

Comment: Possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980427/task-factory-fromasync-with-cancellationtokensource

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

`HttpWebRequest` does not allow you to easily apply a timeout to asynchronous requests.

I recommend you use the more modern `HttpClient`:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    var response = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, url));
}
```

If you are stuck in `HttpWebRequest` land, then you can use a timer that calls `Abort` (untested):

```
static async Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponseWithTimeoutAsync(this HttpWebRequest request, TimeSpan timeout)
{
  // Start request and timeout
  var delayTask = Task.Delay(timeout);
  var requestTask = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

  var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(delayTask, requestTask);
  if (completedTask == delayTask)
  {
    request.Abort();
    throw new TimeoutException();
  }
  return (HttpWebResponse)(await requestTask);
}
```

Comment: The second solution returns an error in this line:
 var requestTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

The call is ambiguous